# Break a tcolorbox and remove subsequent empty lines

Tags: listings, tcolorbox

I have some `lstlisting` blocks that I am typesetting as colored textboxes. Some of these blocks contain empty lines; and some of these blocks are broken across page boundaries by a manual `\tcbbreak`. I would like to replace the `\tcbbreak` command with another command that issues a `\tcbbreak` and then removes any subsequent empty lines (even better would be removing any subsequent lines that only consist of whitespace, but I can preprocess my files to make sure all whitespace-only lines are empty).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{escapeinside=!!}
  
\usepackage[breakable,listings]{tcolorbox}
\renewtcblisting{lstlisting}{breakable,listing only}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
  Lines of text
  Inside a TColorBox

  Burma Shave
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}
  Lines of text
  Inside a TColorBox !\tcbbreak!
  
  Burma Shave
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

And before anyone recommends the obvious ("just delete the empty file from the source when you put in the `\tcbbreak`"), for my real use case I will need to use the same source both for paginated output (where the breaks should be there and should gobble up subsequent empty lines) and non-paginated output (where the breaks should not be there and the empty lines should be left intact).

Comment: If that helps, I can use vanilla `\tcbbreak` where the next line is not empty, and some `\tcbbreakandgobblethenextline` where the next line is empty.

Comment: `emptylines=0`, which suppresses *all* empty lines is not an option, I assume?

Comment: @JasperHabicht no, I have lots of empty lines I want to keep that are not just after a `\tcbbreak`.